# Facebook SDK for Android 2.3?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm thinking about using the Facebook SDK to track my Android app installs, but its only compatible with Android 4 and above. Is there an older version or something that will work with Android 2.3 and above? (I'm only interested in tracking installs, dont need any of the other features)

Comment: Facebook SDK v4.6.0 wants minSdkVersion=15. Have you tried Facebook SDK v4.5.1?

Comment: Awesome yeah I see they raised the minSdkVersion for v4.6.0, unfortunately I can't find anywhere in the docs that says what the minSdkVersion is for v4.5.1, and if its <= 9. Thanks for the tip though i'll probably try installing it and find out

Comment: The minSdkVersion prior to 4.6 is 9. The Facebook SDKs track the native Facebook apps in terms of minSdkVersion, which is why it's been updated to 15.

Comment: Just want to mention that the minimum Android SDK was upped to 9 in Facebook SDK v3.17. So from v3.17 to v4.5.1 the minSdkVersion required by Facebook is 9. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-3.x#ver3_17_0